# Connecting to Com5: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

Tags: c#, python, exception, serial-port, device

I am trying to access my COM5 port at a baud rate of 250000 bits per second using the following c# code but get the exception message below at the line `selectedbaudrate = Convert.ToInt32 (cmbBaudRate.SelectedItem.ToString());`. Using the [pronterface.py](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun) program I can access my device at this rate. Why do I get `0` on the `selectedbaudrate` variable when I wrote `250000`?

```
private void buttonOpenPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                                   
{
    string selectedportname;                                                                    
    int selectedbaudrate;
    selectedportname = combportnumber.SelectedItem.ToString();                                  
    selectedbaudrate = Convert.ToInt32 (cmbBaudRate.SelectedItem.ToString());                  
    port = new SerialPort(selectedportname, selectedbaudrate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);    
    port.DtrEnable = true;
    port.Open();                                                                               
    port.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;    
}
```

Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
      Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
      Source=PC Host
      StackTrace:
           at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.buttonOpenPort_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Catia V5 Projects\HF08 Hexapod\Version 05\Host PC Software\PC Host 13\PC Host\Form1.cs:line 106
           at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
           at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
           at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in D:\Catia V5 Projects\HF08 Hexapod\Version 05\Host PC Software\PC Host 13\PC Host\Program.cs:line 18
           at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
           at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
      InnerException:
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to check the values of the variables?

Comment: ChrisF, yes strange thing is that `selectedbaudrate` is 0 when I specified 250000.

Comment: Then the problem is in the code that is supposed to set the `selectedBaudRate` or it's getting overwritten after you set it.

Comment: Thanks Chris, how can I fix that?

Comment: @Arthur Mamou-Mani: "null" does not mean "zero". null means that a variable which should "point" to an object currently "points" to nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, simple solution: I have added the value 250000 to the dropdown values in the form and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Either cmbBaudRate or cmbBaudRate.SelectedItem is null

Comment: Why is it null when I specified 250000 though?

Comment: cmbBAudRate is, I guess, a ComboBox. Maybe it is not yet created when your code is executed ( == cmbBaudRate is null). Or maybe no item in the combo box is selected at that time ( == cmbBaudRAte.SelectedItem is null)

Comment: @Arthur Mamou-Mani: I have the feeling that you are misinterpreting the NullReferenceException. It does not mean that the value is zero, it means that your are trying to use an uninitialized reference to an object.

Comment: Thank you, I did confuse them and did not know about `uninitialized reference to an object`. I will look into that. The cmdBaudRate variable was defined as 0 when i debugged which was a bug as I specified a certain number. I think the box simply did not recognize the value that I manually enetered. It works now.